# Can a java socket make multiple back to back writes without overwhelming the receiving socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm quite new to socket programming. I've noticed that `BufferedReader.readln()` blocks until there is something to read from the other end but `PrintWriter.println()` just throws out data like ninja stars.

Most socket examples I've seen on the internet are simple read-write-read-write  programs.

If my program has the server call println() back to back a multiple times to send different strings, and the client socket needs to read each line and process the string **in between** each read, is it possible for the server to overwhelm the client with data? Could some data end up lost?

Is it a must to set up a "response" kind of logic in my program, i.e. where the server sends data and waits for a "go ahead" from the client before continuing?

Also does this differ bases on the InputStream/OutputStream implementation being used (like Data or Object Input/Output streams)?

I don't know if this makes a difference or not but these are programs I'm running in an android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is all taken care of for you by the TCP spec.  It's really complicated to explain, but there's algorithms in TCP to deal with sending and receiving window size, exponential backoff and recovery, acknowledgement of data received, etc.  Unless you're dealing with something like realtime video streaming where latency is an issue, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: So TCP is a stream socket-  it sends a series of bytes in order.  THe send window is the set of bytes which the sender is sending but has not yet received acknowledgement of.  There's also a receive window, which is the set of bytes the receiver is expecting to see all incoming data come in that range (because data can come out of order and the receiver fixes the order).  But this is all stuff you don't need to worry about because its built in.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the sender overruns the receiver it will block in blocking mode, or get zero length writes in non-blocking mode. This happens in TCP, not Java.